# OpenCV Cascade Classification with Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOGs) feature type

Tags: opencv, classification, object-detection

I am trying to use the OpenCV's cascade classifier based on Histogram of Oriented Objects  (HOGs) feature type -- such as the paper *"Fast Human Detection Using a Cascade of Histograms of Oriented Gradients"*.

Searching in the web, I found that the Cascade Classificator of OpenCV only supports HAAR/LBP feature type ([OpenCV Cascade Classification](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/objdetect_cascade_classification.html)).

- Is there a way to use HOGs with the OpenCV cascade classifier? What
  do you suggest?
- Is there a patch or another library that I can use?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I've kept my search, when I finally found in [android-opencv](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/Smu-0aEzsPw) that there is a trunk in Cascade Classifier which allows it to work with HOG features. But I don't know if it works...

Link: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/6853

**EDIT 2**

I have not tested the fork above because my problem has changed. But I found an interesting link which may be very useful in the future (when I come back to this problem).

This page contains the source code of the paper "Histograms of Oriented Gradients for
Human Detection". Also, more information. http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/soft/olt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now seems to be available also in the non-python code. opencv_traincascade in 2.4.3 has a HOG featuretype option (which I did not try):

```
 [-featureType <{HAAR(default), LBP, HOG}>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me a URL with this documentation?  I searched in this [page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html), but I think I may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find any documentation on this. What I posted is the output of my opencv_traincascade.exe

Answer (score 3):

If you use OpenCV-Python, then you have the option of using some additional libraries, such as [scikits.image](http://scikits-image.org/), that have Histogram of Oriented Gradient built-ins.

I had to solve exactly this same problem a few months ago, and documented much of the work (including very basic Python implementations of HoG, plus GPU implementations of HoG using PyCUDA) at this [project page](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~ely/faceparts/software.html). There is code available there. The GPU code should be reasonably easy to modify for use in C++.

Comment: Thank you @EMS! It is very well documented. I have two questions: _1)_ Did you perform a `Cascade Classifier` to select the HOG features which best represents the window? and, if positive, _2)_ Did you developt your own `Cascade Classifier` or have you modified the OpenCV version?

Comment: I did not use a cascade classifier, so I can't help there. In general, I dislike OpenCV and prefer to use scikits.learn in Python, and so most of my classifiers are SVM-based. I am not sure what the OpenCV Cascade Classifier accepts as input, but it might not be too hard to compute the HoG feature descriptors in Python, store them to text files, and then manipulate them and load them into C++ in such a way that you can easily feed them into OpenCV. Often it's easier to split the computation like that, into a descriptor-computation phase followed by a feed-descriptors-to-classifiers phase.

Comment: The link is down now. May I kindly ask you to publish it on Github or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `cv::CascadeClassifier` with `HOG` features. To do this just load it with `hogcascade_pedestrians.xml` that you may find in `opencv_src-dir/data/hogcascades`.

The classifier works faster and its results are much better when it trained with `hogcascade` in compare with `haarcascade`...

Comment: Hi, Alexey! Thanks for your answer. Which OpenCV version is that?